# VBA error on making different list validation depending on a cell`s value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to validate a specific column which uses a List validation. If (“Table (T)/ Line (L)” column = “L”) use a specific table, if (“Table (T)/ Line (L)” column = “t”) use another table. I use this code below but it is not working-the list has wrong values:

```
 Function check_alignment_column()

Dim cell As Range, j As String


msg = ""
Set rngCheck = Range([c3], Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
Set rngcheck2 = Range([m3], Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp))

For Each cell In rngCheck

If cell.value = "L" Then

With rngcheck2.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=Lists!E2:E5"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

End If

If cell.value = "T" Then
    With rngcheck2.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=Lists!F2:F29"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True

End With
End If

   Next cell

 End Function
```

Comment: Could you post the Error message you are getting after !!

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jwmo7i The error is that no List is shown here, it must be:                                                                                        Alignment Line
Align Text Left
Align Text Right
Center
Justify

Comment: and for the other cell is the same, it doesn`t use the other list